# Can you get the source code of a bot through your website?

Tags: python, selenium, bots

I ran a website and I also wrote a bot and set that to run over the website. I want to know, is there anyway for me to realize the source code behind my bot through the website?

By the way, the bot is written in Python and it's intended for find the ways someone can spam my website.

Comment: That's potentially a fairly complex question. How does the bot work? Any code samples?

Comment: Realize? Do you mean release?

Comment: Well I have a website and I have written a bot using Python for spamming to determine my website's bugs and patch them in order to make improve my website's stability against spammers. Now, a question has been going in my mind for a long time. Is it possible for me who owns a website, determine the source code for the spammer bot attacking my website?